# Can I use Monte Carlo method to approximate PDF of sum of dependent random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that I have two dependent random variable, *X* and *Y*, can I use Monte Carlo method to estimate the PDF of $X+Y$?

As a special case suppose that $X=Z_1+Z_2+Z_3$ and $X=Z_2+Z_3+Z_4$, and lets say we know the PDF of all the $Z_i$'s and we know that $Z_i$'s are independent. Suppose that we want to find the PDF of $X^2+Y^3$. Can I generate, for example, 1000 samples (or more) for each $Z_i$ and find the PDF of $X^2+Y^3$?

Comment: 1. Generate a million drawings of $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3$ and $Z_4$. 2. Then use those drawings to generate a million values of $X$ and $Y$, and so a million values of $W = X^2 +Y^3$. 3. Then you can plot a histogram of your $W$ data ... /// This does not give you the pdf of $W$, but it does give you an empirical Monte Carlo approximation of the true pdf of $W$, which is a great way of checking any theoretical work you may do.

Comment: Thank you. just a question: If, for a given $r$, I want to find $P(X^2+Y^3<r)$, I can use a million values of $W=X^2+Y^3$ and check how many of them are less than $r$, right? Does it give me  a good approximation for the probability $P(X^2+Y^3<r)$?

Comment: How should I make sure that 1 million sample is enough? I mean, is there any theorem or lemma about how many samples I should choose for Monte Carlo?

Comment: Yes - it should give a good approx of the probability you seek. Is 1 million enough? It will depend on the distribution, and the value of $r$:  if you have fat tails, and you are looking at some extreme value, then 1 million may not be enough. Simply run the same test a few times, and see if the answer you get back is stable (similar values), or if it jumps around. More appropriately for this site, if you specify the distributions of the $Z_i$, you may be able to attain an exact theoretical solution. Then use Monte Carlo methods just to check that it matches.